# Open Excel file from URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I want to open Excel File from javascript

I am trying below code, it is opening the Excel file but the content is not correct as file is getting opened as [ReadOnly].

window.open('ms-excel:ofe|u|http://some-host-name.com/filestest.xlsx');
Can I open the file without [ReadOnly] using similar code?

Comment: Are you using office JS API?

Comment: no. I am using windows.open only.
haven't tried any API.